# How to quote the grouped data frame it self in the function in ddply()

Tags: r, plyr

It is possible to apply certain function in the grouping of data frame by certain variables with ddply(), but how to quote the grouped data frame as the argument of the function?

Take min() as an EXAMPLE:

What I have:

```
> BodyWeight
  Treatment day1 day2 day3
1         a   32   33   36
2         a   35   35   26
3         a   33   38   46
4         b   23   24   25
5         b   22   16   34
6         b   36   35   37
7         c   45   45   39
8         c   29   26   12
9         c   43   27   36
```

What I want:

```
Treatment min
1         a  26
2         b  16
3         c  12
```

What I did and what I got:

```
> ddply(BodyWeight, .(Treatment), summarize, min= min(BodyWeight[,-1]))
  Treatment min
1         a  12
2         b  12
3         c  12
```

The min() is just an example, unspecific solutions are desired.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to summarize by Treatment and Day.  The issue is you have days in multiple columns.  You need to convert your data from the wide format its in (multiple columns) into a long format (key-value pairs).

```
library(tidyr)
library(plyr)

bw_long <- gather(Bodyweight, day, value, day1:day3)

ddply(bw_long, .(Treatment, day), summarize, min = min(value))
```

p.s. Check out the successor to `plyr`, `dplyr`

Comment: Thanks all the same. But the min( ) is just an example, as a matter of fact, in practical work, more complex custom functions taking split data frame as argument will be applied.

Comment: I believe that `plyr` evaluates all the pieces of the split data frame separately , so you can use the `$` operator to access the variables you want, (e.g. `min(Bodyweight$day1)`.  I still recommend you checking out `dplyr` and standard-evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(BodyWeight)`), grouped by 'Treatment', `unlist` the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) and get the `min` value.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(BodyWeight)[, .(min = min(unlist(.SD))) , by = Treatment]
#   Treatment min
#1:         a  26
#2:         b  16
#3:         c  12
```